# What is a possible pseudo code for this code?

Tags: java, pseudocode

What is a possible pseudo code for this code?

I tried the following

1. create string called input which takes user input
2. create Arraylist to store the input//create the scanner and declare it
3. prompt the user to enter a word or phrase to reverse
4. Use a for loop to reverse the word
5. create a new string to store the reversed word
6. display the new string

code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadingDataFromTheUser {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input;
    ArrayList <String> words = new ArrayList <String>();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a word or enter q to terminate program: ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        words.add(input);
    }while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("q"));
    int size =(words.size()-1);

    for (int index=0; index<size;index++) {
        String string;
        String reverseWord ="";
        string = words.get(index);
        for (int value = string.length()-1; value>=0;value--) {
            reverseWord+=string.charAt(value);
        }
        System.out.println(reverseWord);
    }
    scan.close();

    }
     }
```

---

EDIT: What is a pseudo code? How is it written in the Java programming language?

Comment: English sentences do not count as "psoudocode".

Comment: English sentences are used in "algorithms"

Comment: There is no pseudo-code at all, there is an user-story

Comment: By your radical edit, I must say to do some research first, then come here and ask a specific question, like problems when converting your code into pseudo code.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati yes but using sentences only describes the algorithm, it is not the pseudo code of the algorithm.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I know that. I only commented on that because he used English to write pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write it in this way.

```
1. Start
2. Read word as string
3. Take reverse as string
4. Take i
5. For (i=word.length-1; i>=0; i--)
   do
       1. Take ch = word.charAt(i)
       2. reverse += ch
   done
6. Print reverse
7. Stop
```

Hope this helps.